# Terraform and Github Actions

Tags: makefile, terraform, github-actions

I have a Makefile to compile Terraform code. When I am running `Makefile up` locally, everything is working correctly.

**Makefile**

```
BACKEND_CONFIG =    -backend-config=resource_group_name=${AZURE_TERRAFORM_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME} \
                    -backend-config=storage_account_name=${AZURE_TERRAFORM_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME} \
                    -backend-config=container_name=${AZURE_TERRAFORM_STORAGE_CONTAINER_NAME} \
                    -backend-config=key=${AZURE_TERRAFORM_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME}.tfstate \

VARIABLES = -var=path=${PWD}/config/resource-groups \

all:

up: init plan apply

down: init destroy

init:
    terraform init -reconfigure ${BACKEND_CONFIG} src

plan:
    terraform plan ${VARIABLES} -out="plan.out" src

apply:
    terraform apply plan.out

destroy:
    terraform destroy ${VARIABLES} src

.PHONY = all init plan apply destroy up down import az_up az_down
```

What I am trying to do now is to run `Makefile up` whenever I am making a push request. I added all of my secrets in Github secrets and created a Github actions.

[image]

**terraform.yml**

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
    - dev
  pull_request:

jobs:
  terraform:
    name: 'Terraform'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment: production
    defaults:
      run:
        shell: bash
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: build application
      run: make up
      working-directory: ./infra_as_code
```

**Makefile (new)**

```
BACKEND_CONFIG =    -backend-config=resource_group_name=${{ secrets.AZURE_TERRAFORM_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME }} \
                    -backend-config=storage_account_name=${{ secrets.AZURE_TERRAFORM_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME }} \
                    -backend-config=container_name=${{ secrets.AZURE_TERRAFORM_STORAGE_CONTAINER_NAME }} \
                    -backend-config=key=${{ secrets.AZURE_TERRAFORM_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME }}.tfstate \

VARIABLES = -var=path=${PWD}/config/resource-groups \

all:

up: init plan apply

down: init destroy

init:
    terraform init -reconfigure ${BACKEND_CONFIG} src

plan:
    terraform plan ${VARIABLES} -out="plan.out" src

apply:
    terraform apply plan.out

destroy:
    terraform destroy ${VARIABLES} src

.PHONY = all init plan apply destroy up down import az_up az_down
```

error I am getting in Github Actions:

```
Run make up
  make up
  shell: /usr/bin/bash --noprofile --norc -e -o pipefail {0}
terraform init -reconfigure -backend-config=resource_group_name=} -backend-config=storage_account_name=} -backend-config=container_name=} -backend-config=key=}.tfstate  src
Too many command line arguments. Did you mean to use -chdir?
make: *** [Makefile:15: init] Error 1
Error: Process completed with exit code 2.
```

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely wrong:

```
BACKEND_CONFIG =    -backend-config=resource_group_name=${{ secrets.AZURE_TERRAFORM_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME }} \
                    -backend-config=storage_account_name=${{ secrets.AZURE_TERRAFORM_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME }} \
                    -backend-config=container_name=${{ secrets.AZURE_TERRAFORM_STORAGE_CONTAINER_NAME }} \
                    -backend-config=key=${{ secrets.AZURE_TERRAFORM_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME }}.tfstate \
```

First, if you want to put explicit `$` characters in a makefile recipe you need to escape them with `$$`.  That's why you're getting this error: make is trying to expand these as make variables.

Second, if you want to pass these through the shell, you have to quote them for the shell.  I'm assuming that you want the literal string `${{ ... }}` to appear, in which case you want single quotes:

```
BACKEND_CONFIG =    -backend-config=resource_group_name='$${{ secrets.AZURE_TERRAFORM_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME }}' \
                    -backend-config=storage_account_name='$${{ secrets.AZURE_TERRAFORM_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME }}' \
                    -backend-config=container_name='$${{ secrets.AZURE_TERRAFORM_STORAGE_CONTAINER_NAME }}' \
                    -backend-config=key='$${{ secrets.AZURE_TERRAFORM_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME }}.tfstate'
```

(are you sure it's OK to add this whitespace after `{{` and before `}}`?)

I know nothing about terraform or github actions so I have no idea if this syntax is what it wants, but it will pass through both make and the shell correctly.

Answer (score 1):

${{ }} are replaced by github actions before the actual execution. Therefore that will not work within the Makefile.
Best option would be to use Make variables in the makefile and set them when calling Make:

```
BACKEND_CONFIG =    -backend-config=resource_group_name=$(AZURE_TERRAFORM_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME) \
                -backend-config=storage_account_name=$(AZURE_TERRAFORM_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME) \
                -backend-config=container_name=$(AZURE_TERRAFORM_STORAGE_CONTAINER_NAME) \
                -backend-config=key=$(AZURE_TERRAFORM_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME).tfstate \
```

Then in github actions:

```
 - name: build application
      run: make AZURE_TERRAFORM_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME=${{ secrets.AZURE_TERRAFORM_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME }} \
           AZURE_TERRAFORM_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME=${{ secrets.AZURE_TERRAFORM_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME }} \
           AZURE_TERRAFORM_STORAGE_CONTAINER_NAME=${{ secrets.AZURE_TERRAFORM_STORAGE_CONTAINER_NAME }} \
           AZURE_TERRAFORM_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME=${{ secrets.AZURE_TERRAFORM_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME }} \
           up
      working-directory: ./infra_as_code
```

I'm not a real Makefile expert, but as far as I know variables are used with $(VAR), not with '{' in make. But maybe ${} is also working.

Comment: makefiles can use both `$(foo)` and `${foo}` interchangeably.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I am using your suggestions but I am getting ` *** No rule to make target ' up'.  Stop.`

Comment: This error message usually shows up, when there's no Makefile in the directory. Now I'm guessing: Could you instead of using working-directory call make up with the -C option like this: make -C ./infra_as_code <all the variables> up